# How do I get back to the parent frame in wxWidgets C++?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have created this login form. It works like this: cMain is the main login class where you put your login credentials, user_reg is the user creation class. I want to go from cMain frame to user_reg frame and back. Until now I have gone around the problem by just not closing the cMain frame but to me this is not the solution. Is there any way that I can go cMain -> user_reg -> cMain ?
Here is what I tried

```
//cMain.h
#pragma once
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/msgdlg.h"
#include "wx/font.h"
#include "user_reg.h"
#include "account.h"
#include "gui.h"
#include <fstream>

class cMain : public wxFrame
{
public:
    cMain();
    ~cMain();

private:
    gui* m_frame2 = nullptr;
    user_reg* m_frame3 = nullptr; //Works fine
public:
    //Ignore this
    wxButton* m_btn1 = nullptr;
    wxStaticText* m_text1 = nullptr;
    wxStaticText* m_text2 = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn2 = nullptr;
    wxTextCtrl* m_txt1 = nullptr;
    wxTextCtrl* m_txt2 = nullptr;
    wxListBox* m_list1 = nullptr;
    wxMessageDialog* m_msg1 = nullptr;
    void OnLogin(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    void OnRegister(wxCommandEvent& evt);

    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

//user_reg.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "wx/wx.h"
#include "wx/msgdlg.h"
#include "account.h"
#include "encrypt.h"
#include "cMain.h"

class user_reg : public wxFrame
{
public:
    user_reg();
    ~user_reg();
private:
    cMain* m_frame1 = nullptr; //Does not work, error here
public:
    //Ignore this
    wxTextCtrl* m_txt1 = nullptr;
    wxTextCtrl* m_txt2 = nullptr;
    wxTextCtrl* m_txt3 = nullptr;
    wxButton* m_btn1 = nullptr;
    wxMessageDialog* m_msg1 = nullptr;

    void onRegister(wxCommandEvent& evt);
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};
//cMain.cpp

...
m_frame3 = new user_reg(); //Works fine
    m_frame3->Show(); //Works fine
    Close(); //This should not be here, this represents the ideal use case
    evt.Skip();
...

//user_reg.cpp
...
    m_frame1 = new cMain(); //Does not work
    m_frame1->Show(); //Does not work
    Close();
    evt.Skip();
...
```

Any help or documentation is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do what you want is to use a modal dialog, i.e. a `wxDialog`-derived class on which you call `ShowModal()`, for your user registration form.

A better solution from the UI point of view might be to just put the user registration controls inside the main frame itself and just show/hide them as needed. E.g. you could use `wxSimplebook` and make the registration form another page in it.

Of course, it is also possible to show another frame, as you're trying to do right now. In this case you probably want to disable the first frame while the second one is shown, and then re-enable it back. This is something that `ShowModal()` does for you automatically.

Comment: Ok so wxDialog will act as a frame but can I still put like wxButton, wxTextCtrl and stuff in it? Thanks for the heads up

Comment: @Denis9365, of course.  What prevents you doing that?